# "There is a loop between service rc.local and mountnfs-bootclean if started"

Tags: init

So this is the error I receive when I try `sudo apt-get upgrade`

```
insserv: There is a loop between service rc.local and mountnfs-bootclean if started
insserv:  loop involving service mountnfs-bootclean at depth 9
insserv: Starting led_aging.sh depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing sudo (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rsyslog
 apache2.2-common
 apache2-mpm-worker
 apache2
 dbus
 dbus-x11
 hostapd
 openssh-server
 ppp
 sudo
```

I am working on the beaglebone black with debian running on it. I have already tried `apt-get -f`, didn't  I get the same error when I try to install new software. I understand that there are some uninstalled packages but I am unable to install them as well.

Comment: Looks vaguely like `led_aging.sh` has bugs. http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.hardware.beagleboard.user/69174

Comment: May be it could be helpful: [https://github.com/CharlesJGantt/BeagleBone-Black-led_aging-script-replacement-code](https://github.com/CharlesJGantt/BeagleBone-Black-led_aging-script-replacement-code)